# facing issues with transactions in Truclient script

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, truclient

Hi I am working on truclient scripts I have grouped some steps into various transactions but while replaying i found in replay log step was started before transaction starting.

```
t=00001031ms: ** 1: Navigate to LR.getParam("pURL") ** started    [MsgId: MMSG-204251]
Notify: Transaction "Search_T01_LaunchURL" started.
Notify: Transaction "Search_T01_LaunchURL" ended with "Pass" status (Duration: 4.9533).
t=00006391ms: ** 1: Navigate to "LR.getParam("pURL")
```

** successfully completed

In the above lines Navigate to `LR.getParam("pURL")` is inside the transaction but it is started executing before the `Search_T01_LaunchURL` transaction so that if the step fails then we will get the transaction was pass.

Please kindly advice..

Answer (score 0):

Change your End Event to 'Step network completed'. If it is set to 'Automatic:Not set' or 'Action completed', you will see this behavior.